# RegEx to match a particular string in a file

Tags: awk, sed

I want to match just a part of the string, using sed or awk

My string:

```
OPC_NODENAME=abcd123.xy.net
```

Desired result:

```
abcd123.xy.net
```

Comment: It's always trivial to print the output you want and much harder to exclude the output you don't want. Post a few lines of sample input and expected output showing your target string in context in interesting/difficult configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below awk command,

```
awk -F= '/OPC_NODENAME=/{print $2}' file
```

Through sed,

```
sed -n '/OPC_NODENAME=/s/^.*=//p' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to get the value of `OPC_NODENAME=` in your file, (perhaps config file)  I would do

```
grep -Po '^\s*OPC_NODENAME\s*=\s*\K.*' file
```

Comment: @user3834663: If you have only this single string and GNU grep: `echo 'OPC_NODENAME=abcd123.xy.net' | grep -oP '=\K.*'`

Comment: @Cyrus I guess this should be a comment to the original post, not this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed 's/.*=//' file

echo "OPC_NODENAME=abcd123.xy.net" | sed 's/.*=//'
abcd123.xy.net
```